# Create a document with a specified number of pages

Tags: vba, ms-word

For work, we have to hand paginate original documents. Basically stamp each one with a page number at the bottom. I have a template that has a footer with page numbers, which allows me to place the originals into the printer and simply print the pagination to the bottom, But, as it stands right now, I have to Ctrl+Enter for every page number I need, which is sometimes hundreds, and once in a while thousands.

Is there a way to open the template and have a Pop up window ask how many pages I want, so I have pre-populated the document with X number of blank pages with the pagination?

Comment: From the information given in the question, and assuming there's nothing you haven't told us, yes, it should be possible. But before you ask "how", please do read the site guidelines about asking questions on Stack Overflow in the [help]... FWIW if you need type *anything* on these pages besides page breaks you should look at using a STYLE for that text that has "Page break before" formatting integrated.

Comment: Yes there is a way, using VBA. That said, a quick method to generate a _lot of page breaks, assuming your initial document is empty: type in `CtrlEnter`, select all, paste, select all *again*, then paste again, and so one, each iteration should double the number of pages in your doc.

Comment: I appreciate your responses, there is nothing in addition to the information above I can add, I truly need the ability to open X number of blank pages all at one time. the only "text" would be the footnote Page number which is pre-formatted.

Comment: I have very little VBA knowledge. I will delete my question and attempt to find another source of assistance  to my question.. FWIW, it would appear it would have taken you less time to point out the fault in the code provided, than to point out how inappropriate my request for help is, or to point out my apparent illiteracy in VBA. I appreciate the time everyone spent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub Document_New()

Dim myResult As String

    myResult = InputBox("How many pages?")

    If myResult = "0" Then Exit Sub

    ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.InsertAfter Text:=CStr(String$(CLng(myResult) - 1, Chr$(12)))

    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

@FreeFlow, you're code worked great, except, for needing to add " -1" to your ActveDocumnet line, and Exit Sub before the End Sub.Thanks for the framework to get this solved.

Comment: Ah. The good old 'off by 1' error.  Glad you got it working.  I couldn't imaging having to sit there continually doing Alt-enter.

Answer (score -1):

If you put the following macro into your template and it will run each time you create a new document based on the template.

```
Public Function AutoNew()

Dim myResult                                As String

    myResult = InputBox("How many pages?")

    If myResult = "0" Then Exit Sub

    ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.InsertAfter Text:=CStr(String$(CLng(myResult), Chr$(12)))

End Function
```

Edited following @CindyMeisters observation that New doesn't work.

I tried the code I provided in a New Template I created and indeed it didn't work.  This surprised me.  Revised code which does work is below. Please note.  If I open Word and click on File.New select my template the new macro doesn't work.  If on the desktop/File explorer I right click on the template and select new the code with AutoExec works as expected.  Apologies to all for the misdirection.  I also corrected from Function to Sub.

```
Public Sub AutoExec()

Dim myResult                                As String

    myResult = InputBox("How many pages?")

    If myResult = "0" Then Exit Sub

    ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.InsertAfter Text:=CStr(String$(CLng(myResult), Chr$(12)))

End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried placing this in both "Project (Doc1)" as well as "TemplateProject (Doc1)" but it isn't firing on open. Thoughts? Edited for more info.

Comment: I can get this to run if I open the template, then open a new page, unfortunately, then it is not the template I created with the page numbers I need. It is a completely blank document with the number of pages I want.

Comment: Is your template a .dotm file?

Comment: It's also likely to be helpful if you read this 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/customizing-word/auto-macros'

Comment: Have you actually tried running the code you've suggested, Freefow? It will not work...

Comment: @CindyMeister  Thanks for the heads up

Comment: @FreeFlow, you're code was very close to spot on. See my answer above. I screwed with it a bit and it works a charm.

Comment: The problem was not the name, it's the fact that the first suggestion uses `Function`.

Comment: @CindyMeister  When I went back and tried AutoNew  as a sub I couldn't get it to work.  This is why I was surprised. AutoOpen and AutoExe worked fine but not AutoNew.

Comment: What kind of module did you test it in? And this was creating a new document from a template, not in an add-in template loaded from Startup?

Comment: @CindyMeister.  A standard (not class) module.  The Template (dotm) was in the default template directory (....\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates).  I spent some time on this as I was quite surprised.  Its of no consequence for me but I thought I should mention my surprise.